# Arguments in Setup.py

Tags: ros, rospy, setup.py, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can someone please explain the arguments to generate_distutils_setup ([reference](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html))?

I have two use cases that I have not been able to get working with my catkin releases.

1. Release a script so I can rosrun it
2. Release a library so I can import it in other rospy code.

The 'scripts' argument I've gathered actually means GLOBAL scripts that are run without rosrun. [The relevant code](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg/blob/master/src/catkin_pkg/python_setup.py)  is actually not too helpful for this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70234/arguments-in-setup.py/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2013-07-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [Installing Python scripts and modules](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/catkin/html/howto/installing_python.html) how-to may be more helpful for your use cases.

You are correct that the `scripts` argument is *not* recommended (or needed) for normal rosrun scripts.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-07-31**:
Thanks for your reply. I've updated the wiki to include a link to that page. One related followup question not addressed there is:
What is this mapping? package_dir={'': 'src'})

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-07-31**:
It makes the `src/` subdirectory the root of your Python modules.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2013-07-31**:
Okay, but why is it a dictionary?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-08-06**:
ROS is simply using the standard Python interface. I suppose it allows multiple root directories for resolving module imports. I've never needed anything except the `{'': 'src'}`.